# How to pass an object from the View to the controller through .getJSON in Spring 3

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, getjson

I have this bean:

```
public class RespuestaForm {
    private List<RespuestaUsuario> respuesta;
    private List<Pregunta> pregunta;
    private Long pinId;


    public RespuestaForm() {
    }

    public RespuestaForm(List<Pregunta> pregunta, Long pinId) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
        this.pinId = pinId;
    }

    public List<RespuestaUsuario> getRespuesta() {
        return respuesta;
    }

    public void setRespuesta(List<RespuestaUsuario> respuesta) {
        this.respuesta = respuesta;
    }


    public List<Pregunta> getPregunta() {
        return pregunta;
    }

    public void setPregunta(List<Pregunta> pregunta) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
    }
    public Long getPinId() {
        return pinId;
    }

    public void setPinId(Long pinId) {
        this.pinId = pinId;
    }

}
```

I want to pass an object of type RespuestaForm from my view to the controller, so this is what I do in the jsp:

```
function verificarRespuestasAjax(pregunta, pinId, respuesta, index, array){
    var respuestas ={ "pinId":pinId, 
                      "respuesta": [
                            {"pinId": pinId, "respuesta": "prueba", "preguntaId": pregunta},
                            {"pinId": 3, "respuesta": "Hola", "preguntaId": pregunta}                         
                    ]};

    $.getJSON("../usuarios/comparar_respuestas_JSON", {respuestas: respuestas}, function(verifRespuestas){
        if(verifRespuestas){
            ## etc...
    });
}
```

and this is the method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usuarios/comparar_respuestas_JSON")
public @ResponseBody boolean compararRespuestas(@RequestBody RespuestaForm respuestas){
    try{
        //here I should get the object RespuestaForm
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

but I can't get the object RespuestaForm.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use @RequestBody, then I think the json should be sent as a POST instead of a GET.

This will trigger Spring's MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter (assuming you have Jackson on your classpath). I don't remember if you need to set your RespuestaForm class in the ObjectMapper. First you can try without that to see if it works. It is doesn't, then you can try annotating your RespuestaForm object with @JsonProperty on its setters, so that the mapper knows which field of the Json objects goes to what setter method on your class.